# Изменение родителя подкласса

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Помогите понять, в чем ошибка. Пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы родителем подкласса `Firstvc` стал класс `UITableViewController` следущим кодом:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface Firstvc:NSObject{
@interface Firstvc:UITableViewController{
}
@end
```

Ругается на эту строчку

```
@interface Firstvc:UITableViewController{
```

Вот что пишет

> Expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'interface'

В чем ошибка? Может у меня старый Xcode? Версия 3.2.5. Если так, то как сделать под него?

Comment: 1. Я вижу в вашем коде подряд две секции `@interface` для одного и того же объекта. Что-то тут не так, как думаете?  
2. `<UIKit/UIKit.h>` и `<Foundation/Foundation.h>` - это разные заголовочные файлы разных фреймворков.

Comment: И что делать?

Comment: C  кодом .

Comment: @Sergey4590 я вас не понимаю. Я выше уже сказал, что у вас зачем-то в коде два подряд идущих @interface - этого быть не должно (если не знаете, почему не должно, прочитайте об описании  класса в книге по языку).

Comment: И что делать?Я понял что не должно так быть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> И что делать?

Удалить лишний @interface?

```
@interface SomeObject: UITableViewController
{
    ....
}
@end
```